# Computation of the succession $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(3^{n+1}-3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

For training I have decided to solve this limit of a succession

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left(3^{n+1}-3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right).$$

**My first attempt**:

\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(3^{n+1}-3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right) =\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty } 3^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{3^{n\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}}}{3\cdot 3^{n}}\right)\\
&=\ldots 
\end{split}

I have abandoned this approach because I wanted to use a notable limit (if $\{b_n\}\to 0$) that could probably be useful; but seeing the rounded brackets I have thought that I have occurred many times:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a^{b_n}-1}{b_n}$$

**My second attempt**:

\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(3^{n+1}-3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right) =\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty } 3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\left(\frac{3^{n+1}}{3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}}-1\right)\\
&=\ldots 
\end{split}

Considering only

$$\frac{3^{n+1}}{3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}}=3^{(n+1-\sqrt{n^2-1})}$$

Taking only the exponent I have:

$$n+1-\sqrt{n^2-1}=\frac{((n+1)-\sqrt{n^2-1})\cdot ((n+1)+\sqrt{n^2-1})}{(n+1)+\sqrt{n^2-1}}$$
$$=\frac{2n+2}{n+1+\sqrt{n^2+1}} \tag 1$$

If I take the limit of the $(1)$, easily:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n+2}{n+1+\sqrt{n^2+1}}=1$$

i.e.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}3^{(n+1-\sqrt{n^2-1})}=3$$

Definitely I think that this limit is $\infty\cdot 2=+\infty$.
I think that is correct. Do you users think there are better alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n>1$ you have
$$3^{n+1}-3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}>3^{n+1}-3^{\sqrt{n^2}}=3^{n+1}-3^n=2\cdot3^n.$$

Comment: Just a curiosity: But is there a general rule (or reason) of $3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}>3^n$ or  $3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\geq 3^n$ that I memorize it? +1

Comment: No, it is the other way around.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, in general is it always $\sqrt{f(n)}<n$, forall defined $f(n)$?

Comment: How do I know to do the upper bond?

Comment: No; see the intermediate step. Clearly $n^2-1<n^2$ and so $\sqrt{n^2-1}<\sqrt{n^2}$.

Comment: I am not very convinced that it is $n^2-1<n$. If $n=3$ it is false.

Comment: @Sebastiano It was a typo; I have corrected my previous comment.

Comment: How did you change your comment after 5 minutes? Can I understand please?

Comment: I already changed it before you replied.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way to obtain $\infty$ as the limit:

$$
3^{n+1} - 3^{\sqrt{n^2 - 1}} \ge 3^{n+1} - 3^{n} = 2(3^n) \rightarrow \infty.
$$
Your second attempt seems correct but is more complicated.

Comment: But I'm a poor (or scarce) Prof. :-) :-). Why $3^{\sqrt{n^2-1}}>3^n$? Is there a general rule and what is please? +1

Comment: It easily follows from inequality $\sqrt{n^2 - 1} < n$ (just take the exponent of that inequality). Also note that the inequality is in the opposite direction.

Comment: Yes of course there is a minus sign.